# openSUSE not starting up after failed update

Tags: opensuse

More than failed it was a partial update, when I was updating there was a power failure and my laptop shutdown (battery is broken). Now when I try switching my system on, it shows the chameleon and then it just shows a small cursor at the top left of the screen and stays there forever. Any help to recover?

Comment: tried running run level 3, worked, did a zypper update, it gave me a bunch of programs that wont be installed and said nothing to do. Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought:

- insert installation CD in the drive
- reboot
- start installation
- at the second stage, when the hardware is initialized go to console
- mount your harddisk
- mount CD
- cp -av /your_cd_mount_point /your_harddrive/INSTALLCD
- when done, eject CD, reboot
- run system in runlevel 3
- rpm -qa --last > installed_recently_rpms
- go to repositories management
- disable all repositories
- add local repo from HDD (the one you just installed)
- accept, run software managemet
- find all packages which were recently updated (see point above), choose "update unconditionally"
- accept
- wait and pray
- reboot

Good luck!

Comment: guess what, i tried a lot of solutions, nothing worked. Re installed suse, still same problem !!!! now what ?